# Need the key word for research this

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, menuitem

I want to do something like the picture but I don't know what it's and the key word for search this on google.
Example: i have page A, B, C. Page B is children of A and C is child of B, and now I from A, click B -> click C, so I want on page C have A >> B >> C ( and the link for return page on this )  like picture, sorry about my English and the way I explain for this. 
Thanks for your help ^^!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6URc.png)

Comment: [breadcrumb navigation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadcrumb_(navigation))

Comment: I think the word you are looking for is `BreadCrumb`

Comment: thanks for your help, that's exactly what I was searching for !!!